# null pointer exception at onPostExcecute method in android

Tags: android, web-services

In my project i am using AsyncTask for calling web service.i got null pointer exception when i try to call the web service by passing string values..how can i overcome this exception..below is my code

ValidateActivationCode.java

```
public class ValidateActivationCode extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>  {

    String SOAP_ACTION1 = "http://tempuri.org/ValidateActivationCode";
    String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    String METHOD_NAME1 = "ValidateActivationCode";


    String URL="http://myasp.net/webservice2.asmx";

    private String TAG = "VALIDATING CODE";

    String responseString;
    String responseStatus = "SUCCESS";
    Context context;
    AsyncResponseListener responseListener;


    public interface AsyncResponseListener {
        public void onresponse(String status, String jsonData);
    }

    public ValidateActivationCode(Context c) {
        responseListener = (AsyncResponseListener) c;
        context = c;
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");

        RegToServer(params[0]);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
        responseListener.onresponse("status",responseString);



    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
    }

        private void RegToServer(String Code) {



        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);

        request.addProperty("Code", Code);

        Log.i("TAG","Inside regtoserver before webservice call "+Code);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        envelope.dotNet = true;



        try {
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);

            Object response = (Object) envelope.getResponse();
            responseString=response.toString();


            Log.i(TAG,responseString );

            Log.i(TAG, "Websevice called");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            Log.i(TAG, "FAILED");


        }

    }

    }
```

logcat[image]

Comment: Incredible: 2015 and people are still complaining about `NullPointerException` without posting a StackTrace...

Answer (score 1):

actually please post your stacktrace.

still through a quick look of your code, a possible area of null pointer can be this: 
    Object response = (Object) envelope.getResponse();
        responseString=response.toString();

please check if response if null?
i.e. use this:

```
Object response = (Object) envelope.getResponse();
    if(response!=null)
        responseString=response.toString();
```

Comment: After this null pointer error i can get response string through logcat..but i cant't find why this error occurs.

Comment: So you're getting both the response and the error? And why generalize that catch(Exception e) if you now know the possible errors?